# Adding Lists Together

Tags: c#

I have multiple lists of strings, `IList<string>`, that I want to consolidate in one list showing distinct string and count for each item (like a dictionary). what is the most efficient way to do this?

Comment: Hmm, I thought it was duplicate, but I guess it isn't because of the "dictionary" portion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Dictionary<string, int> count = new Dictionary<string, int>();

foreach(IList<int> list in lists)
  foreach(int item in list) {
    int value;
    if (count.TryGetValue(item, out value)) 
      count[item] = value + 1;
    else
      count[item] = 1;
  }
```

Comment: would this be faster than Linq solution above?

Comment: I think it should be a little faster. However, you should benchmark to see accurately. The primary benefit is compatibility with C# 2.0 compiler.

Comment: im somewhat afraid to rely on linq.

Answer (score 3):

LINQ (certainly the most efficient in terms of code to type and maintain; the overall performance will be *about* the same as any other approach):

if the lists are in separate variables:

```
var qry = from s in listA.Concat(listB).Concat(listC) // etc
          group s by s into tmp
          select new { Item = tmp.Key, Count = tmp.Count() };
```

if the lists are all in a parent list (of lists):

```
var qry = from list in lists
          from s in list
          group s by s into tmp
          select new { Item = tmp.Key, Count = tmp.Count() };
```

Then if you really want a list:

```
var resultList = qry.ToList();
```

Comment: the second example doesnt seem to work. it wont allow the second "list".

Comment: @zsharp - it works fine (I've just double checked). Have you got a local variable called "list"? Note the only variable before the query in the example is "lists".

Answer (score 1):

```
List<List<string>> source = GetLists();
//    
Dictionary<string, int> result = source
  .SelectMany(sublist => sublist)
  .GroupBy(s => s)
  .ToDictionary(g => g.Key, g => g.Count())
```